# The motorists behind Sam honked their horns and cursed his slow speed then, when oncoming traffic cleared, they zipped around him, shaking their fists

Tags: sentence-construction

What is the proper way to state this?

> The motorists behind Sam honked their horns and cursed his slow *speed then, when* oncoming traffic cleared, they zipped around him, shaking their fists.

speed, then, when...

speed. Then, when...

...speed then fortunately, when...

or should I leave it as it already is?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking but "The motorists behind Sam honked their horns and cursed his slow speed then, when oncoming traffic cleared, they zipped around him, shaking their fists." is perfectly fine

Comment: @Kevin The sentence is a mess. It is in no way perfectly fine. Did you not notice the use of "speed then, when"?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with introducing a relative clause with *when*!

Comment: I would go with period, new sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence as written is rather close to being a run-on and therefore hard to follow. I would definitely break it into two sentences, but the "then" is not really necessary in my opinion. Obviously "when the traffic cleared" happens after the honking and cursing. So I would write:

> The motorists behind Sam honked their horns and cursed his slow speed. [When/Once] traffic cleared they zipped [around/past] him while shaking their fists.

I removed the comma at the end because it created too much separation between the other motorists' actions, and inserted "while" to provide a clear distinction between "him" and "them."

Answer (score 1):

It's grammatically fine, how you break it up with punctuation is just a stylistic choice really. It might help to read it out loud, and listen for where you're pausing (add a comma!) or when you're finishing a thought and starting a new one (add a full stop / period!)

Personally I think the *then* is fine without a preceding comma, it feels more immediate and almost impatient (which is exactly what you're describing):

*They honked their horns then zipped around him when they could*

vs

*They honked their horns, then zipped around him when they could*

which puts more of a pause between the honking and the zipping (which you also might want, because they are being held back and delayed here!)

---

If you do keep the original no-preceding-comma version, I'd drop the *they*. Try it with the relative clause removed:

- *The motorists behind Sam honked their horns and cursed his slow speed then **they** zipped around him, shaking their fists.*
- *The motorists behind Sam honked their horns and cursed his slow speed then zipped around him, shaking their fists.*

I feel like that reads better because there's a pattern to your description and it works well with the breathless run-on feel - the motorists *did this* and *this* then *this*. But like I said, purely a stylistic choice and probably more of a question for a writing forum!